# What is an Anagrammable Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Anagrammable Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Anagrammable Words™ | Not Anagrammable Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ALARM | PANIC |
| ANIMAL | ALIEN |
| BLESSING | KINDNESS |
| BLOOD | PLASMA |
| EGGS | HAM |
| HATTER | HAIR-STYLIST |
| HEART | TICKER |
| FRACTION | TRACTION |
| ONE-OUT | TWO-IN-ONE |
| SAMPLING | SAPLING |
| VERB | VERBAL |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
ANAGRAMMABLE Words™,Not ANAGRAMMABLE Words™
ALARM,PANIC
ANIMAL,ALIEN
BLESSING,KINDNESS
BLOOD,PLASMA
EGGS,HAM
HATTER,HAIR-STYLIST
HEART,TICKER
FRACTION,TRACTION
ONE-OUT,TWO-IN-ONE
SAMPLING,SAPLING
VERB,VERBAL
```

---

**Notes:**

1. It is preferable to include explanation for each Anagrammable Word™, but not necessarily for non-Anagrammable Words™ .
2. Font/case doesn't matter.

Comment: Interestingly, 'alarm' doesn't form *any* anagrams...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil [Malar](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/malar)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: http://anagram-solver.net/ seems to solve both and probably all words.

Comment: @samm82, editing old Word(tm) puzzles is less useful than other kinds of puzzles which need Markdown table-fying, as Lukas Rotter is automating fixing up old Word(tm) puzzles.

Comment: @bobble I just saw the out-of-place "word" tag and thought I'd kill two birds with one stone. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An Anagrammable Word™ is a word that ...

> ... can be combined with one of the typical [anagram indicators](http://bestforpuzzles.com/cryptic-crossword-dictionary/anagram-indicators.html) (or *anagrind*) for cryptic crossword clues to form a common phrase or expression:
>
>  *false* alarm
>  *wild* animal
>  *mixed* blessing
>  *bad* blood ✻
>  *scrambled* eggs
>  *Mad* Hatter
>  *broken* heart ✻
>  *mixed* fraction ✻
>  *odd* one out
>  *random* sampling ✻
>  *irregular* verb ✻
>
>  (I had other, less satisfying alternatives for the ones marked with ✻. The OP has shared the intended answers in the comments, so I've updated them.)

Note:

> An Anagrammable Word™ is not required to be a suitable anagram fodder that yields other words. For example, EGGS does not anagram to anything useful. So the quality of being Anagrammable™ does not rely on being an anagram of something, only on forming fixed expressions with anagram indicators.
>
>  (There are two questions on PSE that use anagrams to define two of the expressions here: [mixed blessing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40748/cryptic-crossword-clue-seblings) and [scrambled eggs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/gegs-9-4-a-british-cryptic-crossword-clue), but in my opinion neither is very good, because the resulting anagrams are not really words. Plus, these clues lack definitions.)

Comment: You're good at solving these

Comment: Very nice! My original intentions for some of them were : (rot13) onq oybbq, oebxra urneg, zvkrq senpgvba, enaqbz fnzcyvat, veerthyne ireo.

Comment: Yes, these are all better, especially broken heart and mixed fraction, which now seem obvious. They are also all adjectives, which makes for a nicer pattern.