# What is a Lonely Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Lonely Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| LONELY WORD™ | NOT LONELY WORD™ |
| --- | --- |
| CIVIL | FRIENDLY |
| OVAL* | RECTANGULAR |
| DULL | HANDSOME |
| FOCAL | SIGNIFICANT |
| SHINY | POLISHED |
| BIG | MINIATURE |
| CLOWN | ACROBATIC |
| WHOLE* | BROKEN |
| ULOTRICHOUS | DELICIOUS |
| JUSSIEUAN | COURAGEOUS |
| VACUOUS | HAZEL-EYED |
| MINI | TINY** |
| POROUS | ENORMOUS** |
| DOWDY | WEE* |

*** Disputable**
**** Crowded**

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
LONELY WORD™, NOT LONELY WORD™
CIVIL, FRIENDLY
OVAL*, RECTANGULAR
DULL, HANDSOME
FOCAL, SIGNIFICANT
SHINY, POLISHED
BIG, MINIATURE
CLOWN, ACROBATIC
WHOLE*, BROKEN
ULOTRICHOUS, DELICIOUS
JUSSIEUAN, COURAGEOUS
VACUOUS, HAZEL-EYED
MINI, TINY**
POROUS, ENORMOUS**
DOWDY, WEE*

 *Disputable
**Crowded
```

Hint:

> 1. Lonely does not mean Alone.
>
>   2. I mentioned in comments that fixing the mistake in Ulotricious would not change the fact that is a Lonely Word™. However, it does bring it one step closer to being a Not Lonely Word™.

Comment: Some more examples would be good, if the answer below was not the intended answer.

Comment: @Hack-R I have added more examples. Believe it or not, it is really hard to come up with examples for this one.

Comment: It might be that a non lonely word is composition of one/more lonely word with "ly" or some other word. A lonely word can't be broken into sub parts, but a non-lonely word can. It may be, I ain't so sure.

Comment: Would you like to tell us whether a Not Lonely Word is just a word that isn't a Lonely Word, or whether some words are neither Lonely nor Not Lonely?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, in most cases a lonely word should be one that is not not lonely. However, there are edge cases that could be a bit of a stretch. Still, a word should be either lonely or not lonely.

Comment: What are these two words, ULOTRICIOUS and
JUSSIEUAN?

Comment: @John, I guess I happen to have a spelling mistake in ulotrichous: http://www.wordreference.com/definition/ulotrichous. But it doesn't change anything. And the other one is: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jussieuan

Comment: When you say it doesn't change anything, does that mean that changing the I to an H would still let the word be Lonely, or does it just mean that, if ulotricious were a word, regardless of meaning, it would be lonely?

Comment: Changing I to H would still let the word be lonely. The words have to mean something, i.e. they have to be words.

Comment: @MD I suppose in not lonely words you get two or more words spelled as thou take letters orderly from the beginning.

Comment: For example, Friendly - fried, end . Also, ignore the thou, it's you.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar, Lonely is different from Alone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Partial attempt at an answer [heard something in the chat room while passing by on my way out to bed and came back to give it half a shot]:-

A Not Lonely Word™ is one that:-

> Can be used as an adjective before a word formed by anagramming some or all of its letters, to give a common phrase

A Lonely Word™ is one that is not a Not Lonely Word™.

Examples:-

> **FRIE**NDLY FIRE
>  R**EC**T**A**N**G**ULAR CAGE
>  H**AN**DSO**M**E MAN
>  SIGNI**F**I**CA**N**T** FACT
>  P**O**LI**SHE**D SHOE
>  **B**R**O**K**EN** BONE
>  D**ELIC**IOU**S** SLICE
>  H**A**ZE**L**-E**Y**E**D** LADY
>  **TIN**Y NIT
>  ENORMOUS ROOM / MOUSE / MOOR / MORON (?)
>  **WEE** EWE (?)

Comment: In this sense? http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42355/29343

Comment: @Matsmath, if you look carefully, the patterns used are different.

Comment: @Matsmath: No, not even close. They're both based off common two-word phrases, but the way you can get those phrases is completely different.

Comment: Ahh, I see now, so the matching word is hiding inside. Clever.

Comment: How in life did you come up with this????

Answer (score 15):

A lonely word has

> 5 or fewer letters.

A not lonely word has

> 6 or more letters.

---

**UPDATE**
The new examples, of course, mean this is no longer accurate.

Comment: I feel theres something more

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Quite possible, but there are no counterexamples.

Comment: If this is the intended answer... I have no words. And without different test cases, this is a valid answer nonetheless. +1 for exploiting the lack of better test cases :P

Comment: Indeed the OP should've provided more examples and without them this *is* a correct answer, intentional or not

Comment: @DanRussell, I have added more examples.

Comment: Even though this answer is no longer valid, it could still be useful as a means of deciphering the rule, since we can assume that the length of the word makes it easier to categorize. Now that we know Lonely words can have more than 5 letters, I have to wonder if there are non-Lonely words with fewer than 6 characters...

Comment: Does the new Lonely Word™ `ULOTRICIOUS` have more than 5 letters?  I keep losing count.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404, it is possible to have non-lonely words with fewer than 6 characters. The number of characters is not crucial for the pattern.

Comment: What about VACUOUS?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος When this was posted, it correctly described [all examples provided](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/42666/1).